# Visual C++ Compile Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having a time with this program.  I am working with a data file that has 12 lines, one for each month, and 2 numeric positions after the name of the month.  Example:

January  9  11

I am basically stripping the month name down to the first 3 letters, converting them to uppercase, and bringing in the numbers (integers) to work with them.  I am using VS 2012 and as soon as I uncomment the "Infile >> Student.numBoys" line, I get this raucous compile error:  "p01.cpp(41) : error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int [2]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Naturally, I am not even getting to the data file to begin with.  I've been at this for a couple of hours, so I am going to look away for a bit.  If I am missing something glaringly obvious, please go soft on me.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <assert.h>


    using namespace std;
    using namespace System;

    struct TStudent { char month[10];
                      int numBoys[2];
                      int numGirls[2];
                      int sumStudents[2];
                      int totBoys[3];
                      int totGirls[3];
                      int totStudents[3];
                     };

    const char* AUTHOR  = "Sally George              Assignment #1 \n\n";

    int i;

    void main() {
        TStudent Student;

        Console::Clear();
        cout << AUTHOR;

    ifstream Infile("P01.DAT");
    assert(Infile);

      for (i=1; i<=12; i++)
      {   Infile.get(Student.month, 4);
          Infile.ignore(1);
          // Infile >> Student.numBoys;
          strupr(Student.month);
          cout << Student.month << endl;
          Infile.ignore(80, '\n');
      }

}
```

Comment: Well, why did you expect it to work? C++ streams have no operators for array I/O. The only exception is `char` arrays (decayig to `char *` pointers) used for C-string I/O. You want to output and input arrays - you will have implement it manually (library features can help you here, but still it will be your responsibility). In fact, you might succeed "outputing" an array (which will simply convert it to pointer and output the pointer value - definitely not what you need), but inputing an array will not work.

Comment: Try this instead: `Infile >> Student.numBoys[0];` and the same with 1 if you want to read 2 numbers. Expect a throw if the input data are not numbers though.

Comment: Two big mistakes I made was by putting a size value to my integer declarations.  This made the compiler then assume char.  I then included variables within my structure that were unnecessary.  Clearing those up, I was able to complete my task.  Thank you all for the help!  BTW, I couldn't use arrays for my task, but the answer below was the right answer with the statement after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to individually input to the array elements, like so:

```
Infile >> Students.numBoys[0];
Infile >> Students.numBoys[1];
```

Std. C++ does not define a `>>` operator for arrays, other than `char` array.